# How to convert a Flask simple app to an EXE file (The Flask app is in a PyQt app)?

Tags: python, flask, pyqt

Let's assume I have an `app.py` file (which is basically a Flask app containing routes and simple methods), this file imports/requires a db_manager.py (a file that handles the database queries and..)

Finally, I am using PyQt5 to make the app running in a desktop application-like app.

When I run the pyqt.py (which is the app I'm running the flask app in) it works greatly!

Here is a code snippet for the pyqt app:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from threading import Thread
from app import app as flask_app  # Import the Flask app

class WebAppWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Flask App in PyQt5')
        self.setCentralWidget(QWebEngineView())
        self.showMaximized()
        self.start_flask_app()

        url = QUrl('http://localhost:5000')

        self.centralWidget().load(url)

    def start_flask_app(self):
        flask_thread = Thread(target=flask_app.run, kwargs={'host': 'localhost', 'port': 5000})
        flask_thread.daemon = True
        flask_thread.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = WebAppWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

this approach made my flask app look like a desktop app yes, but I want it to package my full app/folder into a .exe file (one file) with no problems when running it!

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pyinstaller:

```bash
pip install pyinstaller
```

then run

```bash
pyinstaller -F pyqt.py
```

**Please change this name to something like main.py or other than any library name.**

This -F flag will compile your app to one file but your program will take some time to open when you run this file because the EXE has to be extracted every time you run this app. See `pyinstaller --help`

Now, you may encounter a problem of **hidden imports**. I recommend making .spec file having all the information about your application like below. You may see .spec file after the first running of the command above (command for compiling). Edit the blocks in .spec file as shown:

```
    a = Analysis(
        ['runner.pyw'], # Your app main start file name
...
        hiddenimports=['PyQt6', 'os', "json", "uuid"], # Write all imports that are not in the first .py file i.e. pyqt.py in your case.

...
    )
    pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)
    
    exe = EXE(
        pyz,
        a.scripts,
        [],
        exclude_binaries=True,
        name='pyqt', # Your app name that you want to set.
 ...

        icon=['Program\\icon.ico'], # You can add an icon if you want to
    )
    coll = COLLECT(
        exe,
        a.binaries,
        a.zipfiles,
        a.datas,
        strip=False,
        upx=True,
        upx_exclude=[],
        name='pyqt', # again your file name.
    )
```

So, this is the template. Just to clarify:

- ...  means there are some options which I have redacted due to the
  longevity of the answer.
- Look for # symbol, this is you want to look at and change.

Don't get afraid of this mess of settings, this is easy once you get an understanding of it.

You will find your EXE in **dist** folder.

Feel free to ask anything if confused in anything.

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir, I just wanted to ask, did you try this approach before?

Comment: I'm still waiting for your answer on my comment because the answer above is not that clear enough.

Comment: Yes, definitely. Not on Flask apps but other Desktop apps.

Comment: @Nova ask freely what you are confused or not clear in.

Comment: Exactly, because Flask apps are not the exact same as other scripts, Flask apps need a lot of dependencies and configuration, I'm just stuck at configuring these things